# Find a one to one correspondence between the nodes in two graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Consider the two graphs shown in the figure below. As a human, I effortlessly understand how graph 2 was obtained by moving the coordinates of some of the nodes of graph 1. Given two graphs with the same typology, is it possible mathematically to find a one to one correspondence of the nodes? What approaches are there? What approaches would be suitable for this example or something similar?

[image: two graphs]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the [graph isomorphism problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem), essentially. Although you describe it in terms of moving the coordinates of the nodes, that is the easier part.

The difficulty is working out which vertices in one graph map to which in the other; the 'one-to-one correspondence' which is the isomorphism. For an example like this, it is relatively easy to try all possible pairs of vertices from each graph. As the size of the graph grows, however, it becomes increasingly difficult.

If you need to do this computationally, there are various libraries to do so. By hand, it is often enough to notice that two vertices can only be paired if they have the same number of neighbours in each graph. This is an *invariant* property of the vertex, and other invariants - such as how many cycles a vertex is part of - can further filter out the possible number of pairs.